# Preview from YouTube-Videos

Tags: android, android-listview, youtube-api

I want to develop an App with shows YouTube-Videos in a ListView.
Like the original YouTube-App but without the video loads in that. Only a ListView that shows the videos and with one click you go to the YouTube-App which loads the video.

But how can i show the video preview in my app? Is there an API or other tricks that i can use?
My first thought was that i do an image from each video... but .. yeah! :)

Here is an example image
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a http post to this Address:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url={complete youtube url}&format=json
```

where {complete youtube url} is the complete url of the video.

For example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ0sW7KOFhU&format=json
```

Should answer you this JSON:

```
{
author_url: "http://www.youtube.com/user/neiljohnson666",
version: "1.0",
provider_name: "YouTube",
provider_url: "http://www.youtube.com/",
thumbnail_url: "http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/AJ0sW7KOFhU/hqdefault.jpg",
author_name: "Neil Johnson",
type: "video",
width: 480,
height: 270,
title: "Manowar - Warriors of the World HD",
thumbnail_width: 480,
html: "<iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AJ0sW7KOFhU?        feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
thumbnail_height: 360
}
```

So the thumbnail_url is the image you are looking for:

[image: that thumbnail_url]

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: Thank you. That helps a bit. Its cool yeah. Can i also get the Time how long the video is?

Comment: Sure, try this: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/AJ0sW7KOFhU?v=2&alt=jsonc where AJ0sW7KOFhU is the youtube video ID, there is a field with the duration of the video

Comment: brother every where raise your hands into the air we're warriors warriors of the world !